# iPhone Development - Detect User activity

Tags: ios

Can someone please tell me if the following is possible when building an iPhone application.

I simply want small application that does the following:

1. Detects if the phone is being used so is the screen awake?
2. Detect for active internet connection.

Are there easy libraries to use to work out this information.

Comment: What did you ever try? Study the Apple iOS SDK documentation first.

Comment: pjf - I would recommend you to think about Android. No such things in iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*- Detects if the phone is being used so is the screen awake?*

It is not possible as it will violate the privacy of the user. Unless you are talking about detect if your app is being used actively on foreground, background, suspended mode and etc, then it is a Yes.

Example of code:-

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];  
if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground || state == UIApplicationStateInactive){
    //Do Something
}
else{
    //Do Other thing
}
```

*- Detect for active internet connection.*

Yes, it is possible, I am using this https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: Hmmm ok, thats an interesting one. With the active internet connection  I am more interested in monitoring if the device is connecting to internet on other apps more like connection tracking?

Comment: You can only check if the device has internet connection when the user is using your app. You are not able to check what other apps are doing, unless Apple opens up the API in the future.